# Tracking Opens using MailChimp API V3

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm looking to replicate the functionality of this call in V3 of the MailChimp API:
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/reports/opened.php

Is there a way to track campaign opens for an email address in V3?

I've been trying the [Report/campaign/email-activity/subscriber URL](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/reports/email-activity/#read-get_reports_campaign_id_email_activity_subscriber_hash) and I'm able to return all their details but the Activity field is always empty no matter who I call.

Edit: The only way I've found so far is to query the [Member's Activity](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/activity/). This gives an output on all the 'opens' for a specific email address but sadly not a list of campaign specific opens.

Comment: hey, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

If your campaign is multivariate (has more than one email format), then you have to use the campaignId of the combinations to get email-activity. You can get those campaignId's using the endpoint */campaigns/{campaign_id}*. It will be under *variate_settings -> combinations -> id* in the response